# Python Tweepy no response on Stream

Tags: python, json, twitter-oauth, tweepy

Hello i try to listen on a tweet channel using python with libary Tweepy.
I use python 2.7.11 and install Tweepy using pip. When i run the following code i get no response an no error. Can you tell me what the problem is and how can i fix this:

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import time
import json
#EDITED 13:25
from tweepy.auth import API

# Twitter Credentials
ckey = 'Consumer Key (API Key)'
csecret = 'Consumer Secret (API Secret)'
atoken = 'Access Token'
asecret = 'Access Token Secret'

class listener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        try:

            tweet = json.loads(data)

            if tweet["lang"] == "nl":
                print tweet["id"]

            return True
        except BaseException, e:
            print 'failed on_date,', str(e)
            time.sleep(5)

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status


auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
#EDITED 13:25
print api.verify_credentials()
# twitterStream.filter( track=lstZoekwaarde, languages="nl" )
twitterStream.filter(track='christmas', languages="nl")
```

**CONSOLE: api.verify_credentials()**

```
User(follow_request_sent=False, has_extended_profile=False, profile_use_background_image=True, _json={u'follow_request_sent': False, u'has_extended_profile': False, u'profile_use_background_image': True, u'default_profile_image': False, u'id': 169505005, u'profile_background_image_url_https': u'https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png', u'verified': False, u'translator_type': u'none', u'profile_text_color': u'333333', u'profile_image_url_https': u'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1425063736/image_normal.jpg', u'profile_sidebar_fill_color': u'DDEEF6', u'entities': {u'description': {u'urls': []}}, u'followers_count': 7, u'profile_sidebar_border_color': u'C0DEED', u'id_str': u'169505005', u'profile_background_color': u'C0DEED', u'listed_count': 0, u'status': {u'contributors': None, u'truncated': False, u'text': u'aan het werk bij Alfam', u'is_quote_status': False, u'in_reply_to_status_id': None, u'id': 541894460343582720, u'favorite_count': 1, u'source': u'<a href="http://twitter.com/download/android" rel="nofollow">Twitter for Android</a>', u'retweeted': False, u'coordinates': {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [5.207323, 52.0616799]}, u'entities': {u'symbols': [], u'user_mentions': [], u'hashtags': [], u'urls': []}, u'in_reply_to_screen_name': None, u'in_reply_to_user_id': None, u'retweet_count': 0, u'id_str': u'541894460343582720', u'favorited': False, u'geo': {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [52.0616799, 5.207323]}, u'in_reply_to_user_id_str': None, u'lang': u'nl', u'created_at': u'Mon Dec 08 09:58:01 +0000 2014', u'in_reply_to_status_id_str': None, u'place': {u'full_name': u'Bunnik, Nederland', u'url': u'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/ef77325fbde0f5ad.json', u'country': u'The Netherlands', u'place_type': u'city', u'bounding_box': {u'type': u'Polygon', u'coordinates': [[[5.1532516, 51.9976555], [5.2803233, 51.9976555], [5.2803233, 52.0801935], [5.1532516, 52.0801935]]]}, u'contained_within': [], u'country_code': u'NL', u'attributes': {}, u'id': u'ef77325fbde0f5ad', u'name': u'Bunnik'}}, u'is_translation_enabled': False, u'utc_offset': None, u'statuses_count': 186, u'description': u'', u'friends_count': 7, u'location': u'', u'profile_link_color': u'1DA1F2', u'profile_image_url': u'http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1425063736/image_normal.jpg', u'following': False, u'geo_enabled': True, u'profile_background_image_url': u'http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png', u'screen_name': u'ehoeven', u'lang': u'en', u'profile_background_tile': False, u'favourites_count': 1, u'name': u'Erik Hoeven', u'notifications': False, u'url': None, u'created_at': u'Thu Jul 22 14:12:09 +0000 2010', u'contributors_enabled': False, u'time_zone': None, u'protected': False, u'default_profile': True, u'is_translator': False}, time_zone=None, id=169505005, description=u'', _api=<tweepy.api.API object at 0x7efdf2d5a510>, verified=False, profile_text_color=u'333333', profile_image_url_https=u'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1425063736/image_normal.jpg', profile_sidebar_fill_color=u'DDEEF6', is_translator=False, geo_enabled=True, entities={u'description': {u'urls': []}}, followers_count=7, protected=False, id_str=u'169505005', default_profile_image=False, listed_count=0, status=Status(contributors=None, truncated=False, text=u'aan het werk bij Alfam', is_quote_status=False, in_reply_to_status_id=None, id=541894460343582720, favorite_count=1, _api=<tweepy.api.API object at 0x7efdf2d5a510>, source=u'Twitter for Android', _json={u'contributors': None, u'truncated': False, u'text': u'aan het werk bij Alfam', u'is_quote_status': False, u'in_reply_to_status_id': None, u'id': 541894460343582720, u'favorite_count': 1, u'source': u'<a href="http://twitter.com/download/android" rel="nofollow">Twitter for Android</a>', u'retweeted': False, u'coordinates': {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [5.207323, 52.0616799]}, u'entities': {u'symbols': [], u'user_mentions': [], u'hashtags': [], u'urls': []}, u'in_reply_to_screen_name': None, u'in_reply_to_user_id': None, u'retweet_count': 0, u'id_str': u'541894460343582720', u'favorited': False, u'geo': {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [52.0616799, 5.207323]}, u'in_reply_to_user_id_str': None, u'lang': u'nl', u'created_at': u'Mon Dec 08 09:58:01 +0000 2014', u'in_reply_to_status_id_str': None, u'place': {u'full_name': u'Bunnik, Nederland', u'url': u'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/ef77325fbde0f5ad.json', u'country': u'The Netherlands', u'place_type': u'city', u'bounding_box': {u'type': u'Polygon', u'coordinates': [[[5.1532516, 51.9976555], [5.2803233, 51.9976555], [5.2803233, 52.0801935], [5.1532516, 52.0801935]]]}, u'contained_within': [], u'country_code': u'NL', u'attributes': {}, u'id': u'ef77325fbde0f5ad', u'name': u'Bunnik'}}, coordinates={u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [5.207323, 52.0616799]}, entities={u'symbols': [], u'user_mentions': [], u'hashtags': [], u'urls': []}, in_reply_to_screen_name=None, id_str=u'541894460343582720', retweet_count=0, in_reply_to_user_id=None, favorited=False, source_url=u'http://twitter.com/download/android', geo={u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [52.0616799, 5.207323]}, in_reply_to_user_id_str=None, lang=u'nl', created_at=datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 8, 9, 58, 1), in_reply_to_status_id_str=None, place=Place(_api=<tweepy.api.API object at 0x7efdf2d5a510>, country_code=u'NL', url=u'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/ef77325fbde0f5ad.json', country=u'The Netherlands', place_type=u'city', bounding_box=BoundingBox(_api=<tweepy.api.API object at 0x7efdf2d5a510>, type=u'Polygon', coordinates=[[[5.1532516, 51.9976555], [5.2803233, 51.9976555], [5.2803233, 52.0801935], [5.1532516, 52.0801935]]]), contained_within=[], full_name=u'Bunnik, Nederland', attributes={}, id=u'ef77325fbde0f5ad', name=u'Bunnik'), retweeted=False), lang=u'en', utc_offset=None, statuses_count=186, profile_background_color=u'C0DEED', friends_count=7, profile_link_color=u'1DA1F2', profile_image_url=u'http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1425063736/image_normal.jpg', notifications=False, default_profile=True, profile_background_image_url_https=u'https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png', profile_background_image_url=u'http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png', name=u'Erik Hoeven', is_translation_enabled=False, profile_background_tile=False, favourites_count=1, screen_name=u'ehoeven', url=None, created_at=datetime.datetime(2010, 7, 22, 14, 12, 9), contributors_enabled=False, location=u'', profile_sidebar_border_color=u'C0DEED', translator_type=u'none', following=False)
```

Comment: credentials ok? Try this: ```api = tweepy.API(auth)
    print api.verify_credentials() #verify credentials```

Comment: Gerrit! Credentials are fine other wise you get error 401. Where can i put this code?

Comment: Gerrit, i add your code and put the console result in the question

Comment: maybe you receive tweets with tweet["lang"] different from "nl"?

Comment: peru i understand that  tweet["lang"] works like a filter. So if i wan t only the dutch tweets then languages="nl" is the correct statement. Or is this not the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this syntax:

```
twitterStream.filter(track=['christmas'], languages=['nl'])
```

Comment: Thanks!!  I forgot that you must use array's for define languate and tracking words